# How to fix org.hibernate.WrongClassException?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a simple web-application using Spring Boot. I mapped multiple entities from inheritance hierarchy to a single pre-existing table. Here is my base class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kpodr")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula("CASE WHEN k_se = 3 THEN 'FACULTY' WHEN k_se = 4 THEN 'DEPARTMENT' ELSE 'COMMON' END")
@DiscriminatorValue("COMMON")
public class Unit {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "k_podr")
  protected long id;

  ...

}
```

And child classes:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("FACULTY")
public class Faculty extends Unit {
  ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DEPARTMENT")
public class Department extends Unit {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "k_pvu")
  private Faculty faculty;

  ...

}
```

Everything works fine and I can fetch any data I need, even the `Faculty` that owns the `Department`. But now I need to use base `Unit` type to map other entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mesto_rab")
public class Workplace {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "k_podr")
  private Unit unit;

  ...

}
```

When I try to fetch workplaces I get `org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=85] was not of the specified subclass [workload.faculty.Faculty] : loaded object was of wrong class class workload.unit.Unit`.

I found exact place in my code that leads to this exception. If I remove the association between `Department` and `Faculty`, then everything will work as expected.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DEPARTMENT")
public class Department extends Unit {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)   <====|
  @JoinColumn(name = "k_pvu")           <====| Remove this
  private Faculty faculty;              <====| 

  ...

}
```

How to fix `org.hibernate.WrongClassException` and keep the association between departments and faculties?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the row with `id=85` is referenced by a `Department`, but its discriminator formula does not evaluate to `"FACULTY"`.

In other words, you probably have a row `kpodr(id = 85, k_se <> 3)` and another row `kpodr(k_se = 4, k_pvu = 85)` and that's what's causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for reply! The database really have a record `kpodr(id = 85, k_se <> 3)`, but there is no such records as `kpodr(k_se = 4, k_pvu = 85)`. All records with `k_pvu = 85` have `k_se = 3` or `k_se = 5`.

Comment: From your comment I infer that the `k_pvu` is reused for multiple types of relationships between the subclasses. That might be what bothers Hibernate. Does it work if you use `@JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "k_podr", formula = "CASE WHEN k_se = 3 THEN k_pvu ELSE -1 END")` instead of `@JoinColumn` for `Department.faculty`?

Comment: Do you mean `value` attribute instead of `formula`  in `@JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "k_podr", formula = "CASE WHEN k_se = 3 THEN k_pvu ELSE -1 END")`? Otherwise I get this error: `The attribute formula is undefined for the annotation type JoinFormula`.

Comment: Yup, my bad, sorry

Comment: For `@JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "k_podr", value = "CASE WHEN k_se = 3 THEN k_pvu ELSE -1 END")` I get `Unable to find workload.faculty.Faculty with id -1`.

Comment: ...and what happens if you combine it with `@NotFound(action = IGNORE)`?

Comment: Same exception as before: `Object [id=85] was not of the specified subclass [workload.faculty.Faculty] : loaded object was of wrong class class workload.unit.Unit`

Comment: OK, I just realized I made a logical error when designing the formula to use. As a measure of last resort, try `@Formula("(SELECT fac.k_podr FROM kpodr fac WHERE fac.k_podr = k_pvu AND fac.k_se = 3)")`. I still suspect there is simply some data inconsistency in the database, though. If this works and you later find that a `Department` is missing a `Faculty`, then that faculty is the one causing problems

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is not in the source data. I have created copies of the source tables with small amount of test data that cannot be invalid. Exception still occurs and always for the entity to which the faculty belongs. As you can see, `Faculty` has no references to the top entity. But I found the solution: I changed `FetchType` of the `Department.faculty` to `LAZY` and it looks like it works. Perhaps the problem is how the associated entities are fetched by `FetchType.EAGER`.